# Invalid Value Encountered in arcsin

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to transform the following array of positive integers via an arcsin(sqrt(x)) transformation. However whenever I run it the code gives an error. The array is the following:

```
Vs = [33, 27, 658, 5, 102, 4, 196, 16, 66, 39, 165, 41, 116, 0, 480, 23, 70, 8, 534, 43, 214, 92, 2549, 933, 154, 300, 6233, 1150, 156, 4, 2645, 303, 305, 16, 3083, 539, 417, 30, 3987, 451, 429, 0, 2786, 1857, 886, 517, 11020, 783, 470, 609, 1083, 8823, 594, 111, 7664, 1681, 721, 19, 5250, 1800, 721, 135, 3921, 2258, 586, 8, 3163, 3795, 999, 125, 9822, 11302, 940, 21, 3804, 9514, 917, 34, 4511, 5654]
```

And I am trying to transform it using

```
Vs_transform = np.arcsin(np.sqrt(Vs))
```

If you can point out where the error is coming from I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Doesn't arcsin only accept `<=1` values?

Comment: My bad I realized I was accidentally transforming the wrong part of the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sin` of any angle lies between -1 and 1. It follows that the inverse, `arcsin` must be between -1 and 1. You get the warning on the first instance of `np.arcsin` that gets a value > 1 or < -1. After that, the warning is supressed but `nan` is the result.